# Show only tickets in specific State

Tags: otrs

I would like to have in my OTRS the functionality that when a ticket is in a specific state ("comment") this ticket will not be visible anywhere in Dashboard/Orders for all agents except for the Admin agent.

Is there a way to show/hide tickets based on the TicketState for specific Agents only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build custom dashlets for groups, which show only certain tickets. For this you need to create an xml-File and place it in your `Kernel/Config/Files/` directory as it is described in [this blog post](https://blog.otrs.com/keep-an-eye-on-certain-customers/).

In your case you would need to replace the standard dashlets with custom ones, which exclude the state, which is admittedly a little tedious...

Comment: I was searching the whole web, but I missed that blog. Thanks for pointing it out. I will try it.

Comment: The solution is relatively old, but we are still heavily relying on it in our system :-)

Comment: I tested it and it works great. I just had to add a new statetype for my purposes to really enjoy this feature:)

Comment: Additional question. At the end I had to create a new statetype and I filter all states of this type. Unfortunately, it does not work for the state themselves. For example, I have two states - first, second, both are of type "own". The filter line: <Item Key="Attributes">StateType=own;SortBy=TicketNumber;OrderBy=Down;</Item> works, but <Item Key="Attributes">State=first;SortBy=TicketNumber;OrderBy=Down;</Item> does not. Any idea why and how can I make it works for the states directly? Thanks again.